# Estimation with Random Walk 2 Priors

Tags: regression, markov-chain-montecarlo, random-walk, stan, inla

In (https://becarioprecario.bitbucket.io/inla-gitbook/ch-smoothing.html#sec:smoothterms), they show an example of a Random Walk 2 (RW2) prior being used on the LIDAR dataset. For the model set-up, we have that each log-ratio value, $y$, is observed at position $x$. The goal of the regression is to estimate $f(x)$ where $y\sim N(f(x),\sigma^2)$. They place a RW2 prior on $f(x)$, which for the case of regularly spaced $x$ is:

$$
f(x_{i+1})-2f(x_i)+f(x_{i-1})\sim N(0,\tau^2)
$$

My question concerns the hyperparameter $\tau^2$. If $f$ is $f(x)=x^2$, then would $\tau^2$ be estimable? In the case of $x^2$, if I evaluate the finite second derivatives with fixed spacing, then I should find that the value is constant across the grid. I do not understand the role of $\tau^2$ in this case because the second derivative is constant at all evaluation points.

I set up a simulation according to the description above and attempted to estimate a RW2 model on regularly spaced data. In the result from the Stan fit, $\sigma=2.9$, and $\tau=0.0025$. The $\sigma$ parameter is correctly estimated. The model does not appear to have converged though, and I suspect either I did not write the model correctly, or it needs to be reformulated.

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  vector[N] y;
}
parameters {
  vector[N] mu;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
  real<lower=0> tau;
}
model {
  vector[N-2] s = rep_vector(0.0, N-2);
  s =  mu[1:(N-2)] - 2*mu[2:(N-1)] + mu[3:(N)];
  
  target += normal_lpdf(y|mu,sigma);
  target += normal_lpdf(s|0,tau);
  
  target += normal_lpdf(log(sigma) | 1,3);
  target += normal_lpdf(log(tau) | 0,3);
}
```

```
set.seed(123)
xlim=3;delta=0.01
x=seq(-xlim,xlim,delta);sdParm=3#sqrt(1/6)
y=x^2+rnorm(length(x),sd = sdParm)

stanModel=cmdstanr::cmdstan_model(stan_file = 'RW2Demo.stan',exe_file = 'RW2.exe')
stanData=list(y=y,N=length(y),delta=delta)
fit=stanModel$sample(data=stanData,parallel_chains =  4)
fittedTab=fit$summary()

par(mfrow=c(1,2),mai=c(0.75,0.25,0.25,0.25))
plot(x,y,ylab='Observed Values',ylim=c(-5,10))
lines(x,x^2,col='red')
plot(x,fittedTab[2:(2+length(y)-1),]$mean,ylab='Fitted Values',ylim=c(-5,10))
lines(x,x^2,col='red')
```

Comment: I think you need to do some more work to find out if it's a Stackoverflow problem or a crossvalidated problem. Hard to tell what's just a coding issue.